# How to pass an array?

Tags: php, arrays, post, get, methods

How could I pass an array with PHP by GET method?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

In your query string (or POST data, it doesn't really matter), you should end up with this:

```
http://example.com/myscript.php?foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3
```

PHP will parse that into `$_GET["foo"]`, and it will be an array with the members 1, 2, and 3.  How you mangle that from a form is up to you. In the past, I've named different checkboxes "check[]", for example.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like through a form?

```
<form method="GET" action="action.php">
    <input type="text" name="name[]">
    <input type="text" name="name[]">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Notice the name attribute has `[]` in it.

Then in your php:

```
<?php
    $names = $_GET['name'];
    foreach($names as $name) {
        echo $name . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Yes, I want to do it through form (with checkboxes) but this solution didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

You call the script with something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/script.php?foo[bar]=xyzzy&foo[baz]=moo
```

This will result in the following array in $_GET:

```
array(1) { ["foo"]=> array(2) { ["bar"]=> string(5) "xyzzy" ["baz"]=> string(3) "moo" } }
```

You can also leave out the key names in order to get regular array indexing.

Comment: "Notice: Undefined index: category" I get this

Comment: Exactly what query string are you using, and how are you accessing it?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="3" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="4" />

This is the form and I try to print it out with print_r

Comment: And you're using print_r($_GET['category']) to print? If you haven't checked any of the boxes, this is expected behavior. If you've checked  some of the boxes, you may wish to add this, and more of the code to your original question.

Answer (score -1):

As an aside, instead of passing the array by GET, it might make more sense to store the array in the $_SESSION and get it out again later.